# How to use the signUp() method in Supabase to add additional user info when signing up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, supabase, supabase-database

I am attempting to build a Vue.js application that includes authentication with Supabase. I wish to use the built-in Supabase signUp() method to handle additional user data when signing up. To do this, I added a property to the signUp object that stores additional user data, along with the email and password:

```
let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
  email: 'someone@email.com',
  password: 'QQlbOIyZuwutISUzceOz',
  data: { isVendor: true }
})
```

However, when I run console.log after creating the user, I do not see an additional data property added to the user object.

I also tried assigning data to the existing `user_metadata` property in the user object, like so:

```
let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
  email: 'someone@email.com',
  password: 'QQlbOIyZuwutISUzceOz',
  user_metadata: { isVendor: true }
})
```

However, this also did not work. How can I configure the signUp() method (or possibly the registered user portal in my Supabase dashboard) to store additional user data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to docs only way to add extra details while signup is to add in data like this :

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(
  {
    email: 'example@email.com',
    password: 'example-password',
    options: {
      data: {
        first_name: 'John',
        age: 27,
      }
    }
  }
)
```

These data will be added to a column named raw_user_meta_data as a json. if you want to persist this meta data ypu can write a trigger like below.

```
* This trigger automatically creates a user entry when a new user signs up via Supabase Auth.
*/ 
create function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into public.mrbs_users (id, email, name)
  values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'name');
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

Comment: Thank you. This still doesn't work. I added the options property inside the signUp() like you did, but when I create a new user and log user, I do not see ```options``` in the returned object. Is there another way to implement that property?

Comment: const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser() @JS_is_awesome18

Comment: thank you. I was trying to handle .getUser on an older version of Supabase in Vue. I updated the version and now it works. However, I have another issue related to .getUser. I just posted the issue. Would you be willing to check it out? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75328807/supabase-auth-getuser-returns-error-on-vue-router-route-guard

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar issue with an additional user data that I want to put there and although the Vaysage solution works fine I've decided to have some more flexability by creating a new "users" table.
Inside of this new "users" table you can put whatever data you want, later you can query it for something else by it's extra fields but with the normal (Supabase) I cannot see a way at this point.

So, after successfull **signUp**...

```
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email: someEmail,
    password: somePassword,
  });
```

You can put your new user inside of the new "users" table from Supabase:

```
  if (data && data.user) {
    const { error: insertError } = await supabase
      .from("users")
      .insert([
        {
          user_id: data.user.id,
          email: data.user.email,
          username: "Some username !@#$%^&*()",
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Doe",
          age: "21",
          etc...
        },
      ]);

    if (insertError) {
      console.error(
        "Error inserting user into 'users' table:",
        insertError
      );
     }

   }
```

At the moment I find this to be working very well for me and I can quickly check the table inside Supabase and see straight away at a glance what extra data is existing and whats not for the registered users, but this is not the case with the Supabase Authentication at the moment.

Hope this was helpful!

Supabase I'm on => v2.31.0